# Divs won't take up whole page (HTML 4.01 Strict & CSS 2.1)

Tags: html, css

I have multiple `div` elements and what I'd like to do is simply set the `height` and `width` to be `100%` so that each elements takes up an entire page.

This is proving incredibly difficult in HTML 4.01 Strict and CSS 2.1 without positioning them as `absolute` or `fixed`, however, but I want to avoid doing that.

I've tried every single `display` value.

- block
- compact
- inherit
- inline
- inline-table
- list-item
- marker
- run-in
- table
- table-caption
- table-cell
- table-colum
- table-colum-group
- table-footer-group
- table-header-group
- table
- row
- table-row-group

I've tried every `position` value. None of them do the trick.

I've tried setting `html { display: table; }`, `body { display: table-row; }`, and `.div { display: table-cell; }`, but this doesn't work.

**Nothing seems to work unless I `position` each `div` as `absolute` or `fixed`, but I really want to avoid this, and would prefer to `position` each `div` as `relative` since I will be injecting additional `div` elements via JS and I don't want to have to keep track of how many `div` elements there are in order to position them accordingly.**

## CSS

```
html, body {
  width    : 100%;
  height   : 100%;
  margin   : 0;
  padding  : 0;
}

html {
  display  : table;
}

body {
  display  : table-row;
}

.page {
  width    : 100%;
  height   : 100%;
  position : relative;
  display  : table-cell;
}

#red    { background : red; }
#orange { background : orange; }
#yellow { background : yellow; }
#green  { background : green; }
#blue   { background : blue; }
#indigo { background : indigo; }
#violet { background : violet; }
```

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page" id="red">red</div>
  <div class="page" id="orange">orange</div>
  <div class="page" id="yellow">yellow</div>
  <div class="page" id="green">green</div>
  <div class="page" id="blue">blue</div>
  <div class="page" id="indigo">indigo</div>
  <div class="page" id="violet">violet</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried setting the `width` of `html, body` to `700%`, but this doesn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you also include the html?

Comment: Is there any reason you still using HTML4 and CSS2 instead of HTML5 and CSS3?

Comment: @ShadowFiend Sure. It's up there now

Comment: @hcheung of course. no way i'd be using this shit if i didn't have to lol

Comment: Why you dont want to use position absolute? From my perspective there is no other way to do it since all your divs are in the same level and I guess you want that all those divs get the 100% of height of the page

Comment: Did u try `* {margin: 0}`?

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rb1sL2s6/) what you want?

Comment: @ShadowFiend basically, yes, but in HTML 4.01 Strict and CSS 2.1

Comment: @Frankusky i don't want to use `absolute` because i'll be injecting HTML via JS and I don't want to have to keep track of how many DIVs there are and then have to position them accordingly :/

Comment: @ChavaG you really should read the entire question before responding...

Comment: could please try position:fixed , https://plnkr.co/edit/AQ43hzgQT95DkAIdeJTS?p=preview

Comment: @NagaSaiA `fixed` works but i want to avoid `absolute` and `fixed`. i'll edit my question to reflect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change**

```
.page {
   width    : 100%;
   height   : 100%;
   position : relative;
   display  : table-cell;
}
```

**to**

```
.page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: wow. wtf. why does that work?!?!?! i could've sworn i tried that already and it didn't work. maybe it was caching. are you aware of any way to make them display in a row as opposed to a column?

Comment: i don't believe `vw` units weren't available in HTML 4.01 Strict and CSS 2.1, but, yes, just like that minus the extra height/downward scroll. preferably without adjusting the width of the body though

Comment: have you tried it putting in your code if its really not working?

Comment: of course!! i was playing around with it in a browser. not sure why it didn't work initially. maybe a spelling error or something :/

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, try below option

```
.page {
  width    : 100%;
  height   : 100%;
  position : relative;
  display  : table;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/AQ43hzgQT95DkAIdeJTS?p=preview

Comment: Shadow Fiend beat you to it, but your answer does work!!

Comment: thanks Anthony :) , infact, same look and feel can be achieved by removing position:relative also and keeping only height and width for page class

Comment: That is true!! It also works without `display: table` and only `position: relative`. I'm not sure why this works now. I tried this before and it wasn't working. My browser must've been caching the page :/

Comment: yes..that could be the issue but anyway nice to hear that it worked :)

Comment: ty and ty for your help <33

Comment: np Anthony ... happy coding :)